# Complete graph with x vertices on a circle has as many edges of neighboring points as the others. Value of x?

Tags: geometry, coloring

I tried solving this question but cant find any approach to solve it.
We are given an integer $x \ge 2$ and a circle. We need to take $x$ different points on the circle and after that draw line segments joining every possible pair of points. We’ll color the lines green which are joining adjacent points and color yellow others. It is given that the number of green and yellow line segments are equal. Now we need to find the value of $x$.

Comment: The number of yellow line segments grows rapidly. You should be able to find the answer in a minute or less just with trial and error.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "Geometry , I tried solving this question but cant find any approach to solve it." isn't a title. I have taken the liberty to provide one which is more significant.

Answer (score 1):

This is less of a geometry problem than one of graph theory. The number of green segments is $x$, those segments forming a cycle linking the $x$ points together. The *total* number of segments is, by the handshaking lemma, $\frac{x(x-1)}2$.

Now if the number of green and yellow segments are equal, the total number of segments is twice the number of green segments: $2x=\frac{x(x-1)}2$. Solving the quadratic that follows yields $x=5$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Think about what these lines represent. Green are joining adjacent and yellow joining non-adjacent. These seem rather like *sides* and *diagonals* in a polygon. Moreover it is a convex polygon since all the points lying along a circle.

I recommend you draw a couple of pictures for small $x$, say $x=2,3,4$ should be enough to get the idea.

Hope this helps.